# Rails has_one association through mapping table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, polymorphic-associations, has-one

Given these 4 Rails models:

```
class Apple < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one: ?
end

class Banana < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one: ?
end

class FruitMapping < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :fruit, polymorphic: true
  has_one :cart
end

class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

How can I connect the `has_one` of the `Apple`/`Banana` to `Cart`, so that when I write `apple.cart` I will get the relevant Cart (through the mappings table)?

Answer (score 1):

```rb
class Apple < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :fruit_mapping, as: :fruit
end

class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :fruit_mappigns
  has_many :apples, through: :fruit_mappings, source: :fruit, source_type: 'Apple'
  has_many :bananas, through: :fruit_mappings, source: :fruit, source_type: 'Banana'
end
```

Using the `source` and `source_type` options, you can define the polymorphic relationships. If using `source` and `source_type` are depricated in the Rails version you're using you can try

`has_many :apples, through: :fruit_mappings, class_name: 'Apple', foreign_key: :fruit_id`